# how to count no of records in and display in view

Tags: codeigniter

> This error will show when i want to display no. of records in a table.
>   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: h

Filename: views/index.php

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/index.php

> Controller

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in')) {
        $data['h']= $this->admin_model->visitor_count();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

> model

```
function visitor_count() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM create_new_pass");
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

> view

```
<div class="inner">
<?php foreach ($h as $counts){?>
            <h3><?php echo $counts; ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
          <p>Total No. of Visitors till yet</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: your view code is in index.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is problem in your model. You are COUNTing rows and then using num_rows which will allways return 1 (because count will be only one row).
Update your model:

```
function visitor_count() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows FROM create_new_pass");
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

and your view:

```
<div class="inner">
    <h3><?php echo $h['count_rows']; ?></h3>
    <p>Total No. of Visitors till yet</p>
</div>
```

**Or** you can use Query helper methods in your model:

```
function visitor_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all('create_new_pass');
}
```

and your view:

```
<div class="inner">
    <h3><?php echo $h; ?></h3>
    <p>Total No. of Visitors till yet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i follow the above process but it shows an error - Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: h

Filename: views/index.php

Comment: @dipti - do you have these lines in your controller? `$data['h']= $this->admin_model->visitor_count();` and `$this->load->view('index',$data);`.

Comment: Yes i declared in my controller.you can check above i post both controller,model and view.

Comment: @dipti - what do you get, when you add `var_dump($data);` under this line `$data['h']= $this->admin_model->visitor_count();` in your controller?

Comment: @dipti - so please, approve my answer, if it was the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

> Change your view as per

```
<div class="inner">
    <h3><?php echo $h; ?></h3>
    <p>Total No. of Visitors till yet</p>
</div>
```

you return number of records in model so you don't use foreach loop in view direct use data variable.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this direct on view page:-

```
<?php $count4 = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count_rows FROM questions where category='people'")->result(); 
                  foreach ($count4 as $key => $value) { 
echo $value->count_rows;
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change Model by this

```
function visitor_count() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM create_new_pass");
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

> And change your view by this:

```
<div class="inner">
    <h3><?php echo $h; ?></h3>
    <p>Total No. of Visitors till yet</p>
</div>
```